# Jenkins query json api for last successful build details

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to retrieve specific jenkins details about last successful build, such as revision SHA1. I use:

https://jenkins-host/job/job-name/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json?tree=actions[build[revision[SHA1]]]

However, this gives additional data associated with the actions field, is it possible to narrow it down to just the revision SHA1.

I know I can get buildNumber using https://jenkis-host/job/job-name/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have jq(https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) installed, you can use below script to get the SHA1.

`$ curl $JENKINS_URL/job/<job-name>/lastStableBuild/api/json --user <user>:<token> | jq -r -j ".actions[] | select(.lastBuiltRevision) | .lastBuiltRevision.SHA1"`

Replace `<job-name>` with the job you would like to get the revision SHA1.

Replace `<user>`, `<token>` with your own credential.